# How to Redirect the page onclicking any where in the video frame the url linkpage should open

Tags: android, html, cordova

How to Redirect the page onclicking any where in the video frame the url linkpage should open

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $("#ytplayer").attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + getValue("id") +'?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com');
    $("#back").click(function(){

                if(getValue("Animat")==1 || getValue("Animat")==2 || getValue("Animat")==3 || getValue("Animat")==4)
                {
        window.location.href = "Week-Animations.html?Animat=" + getValue("Animat") + "&week=" + getValue("week") + "&tier=" + getValue("tier");
                }});});

<iframe  id="f" width="300" height="320" src=" "  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'start' parameter as the url of the embeded video, that should do the trick.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#start

So, what you need to do is, when the user click a button, change the video url adding a 'start=time' where time is a number (You can use 34m10s to go to 34 mins, 10 seconds). Let me know if that helps.

Cheers mate,

Bob